# Catch the call in API

Tags: php, curl

I have a page wherein it will serve as a for that is connected to my API.php.
In this page I used Curl PUT verb and passed the URL and the data I need to pass which is in the form of an array.

I tried catching the response in the side of the API but to no avail.

Here's my code.

**The URL they need to populate or I think this is the API**

```
http://localhost/sample/index.php/2/users/mil/milastname/09876543212
```

**Legend:**

**Sample** - is the folder where I stored my index.php

**2**      - is the action. In this case 2 stands for PUT verb.

**users**  - is the table in the database which I want to update.

**mil**    - is my firstname

**milastname** - is my lastname

**09876543212** - is my mobile

**MY FORMS**

**index.php**

```
$request = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],'/'));


if ($request[0] == 2) {
$data = array(
  "table" => $request[1],
  "fname" => $request[2],
  "lname" => $request[3],
  "cntct" => $request[4]
);

$url_send ="http://localhost/api.php";
$str_data = json_encode($data);
$post_elements = array('data'=>$data);

if ($request[0] == 2) {
  put($url_send, $post_elements);
  echo put($url_send, $post_elements);
}


function put($url, $fields)
{

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));

echo curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

return $response;
}
```

**Here's my API.php**

```
if ($method == 'PUT') {
$data = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_]+/i','',array_shift($_POST));
echo $data;
die();
}

switch ($method) {
case 'PUT':
  $sql = "update `$table` set $set where id=$key"; break;
case 'POST':
  $sql = "insert into `$table` (user_fname, user_lname, user_contact) values ('$fname', '$lname', '$cntct')"; break;
case 'DELETE':
  $sql = "delete `$table` where id=$key"; break;
}

$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
```

In the part of `if ($method == 'PUT')`

I tried inserting an echo and a die to stop the process to that I can see the array So I can arrange the update query in my method case update. But it returns no result.

Thanks for the help and sorry for the long post. Need to detail it so that I can explain my question clearly.

Thanks.

Comment: It kept on returning a value of 11. And I dont know where that value came from.

Comment: How are initialising `$method` in your API.php

Comment: $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']; so when the curl is executed it will either accept get, PUT, POST or DELETE.

Comment: Is there anyone here? Thanks.

Comment: No one wants to help me?

Comment: Hi @Roi have you solved the issue?

Comment: Yes. I did, I'll have to post it here later. Thanks fr reminding me.